# Detect whether input element is focused within ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

How can I detect whether an input element such as the following is currently focused within a ReactJS render function?

```
<input type="text" style={searchBoxStyle} placeholder="Search"></input>
```

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You can check against `document.activeElement` as long as the input node is mounted and there is a reference to it:

```
const searchInput = React.useRef(null)

if (document.activeElement === searchInput.current) {
  // do something
}

return <input type="text" ref={searchInput} />
```

Another way would be to add event listeners for the `focus` and `blur` events inside the input field:

```
const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false)
const onFocus = () => setFocused(true)
const onBlur = () => setFocused(false)

return <input type="text" onFocus={onFocus} onBlur={onBlur} />
```

Note that this will call a re-render each time the node is focused or blurred (but this is what you want, right?)

Comment: For anyone that finds this post years later: in React 16.x and up it's no longer recommended to use `refs` this way, the new `React.createRef()` functionality should be used. More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 20):

I started with the answer given by David, where he describes two methods, and they both worked for me, but I had concerns about both:

1. On the first case it uses `findDOMNode`, what has some disadvantages: at minimum its use is discouraged, and it can easily be implemented in a way that it is considered an anti-pattern; and also it can make the code slower, by bypassing the virtual DOM and working with the DOM directly.
2. On the second option, create and manage a component state only to find that answer seems too much work, can easily get out of sync, and can cause the component to re-render unnecessarily.

So after trying to explore the issue more, I came up with the following solution:

```
if (this.props.id === document.activeElement.id) {
  // your code goes here
}
```

The same comment on David's answer applies:

> You should not do this in the `render` method though, because the input node might not be mounted yet. Use a lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount`.

Advantages:

- uses the current component properties (which are immutable values)
- doesn't require state management, and therefore won't cause unnecessary re-rendering
- doesn't require DOM traversing, so performance should be as good as it gets
- doesn't require creating a component reference

Requirements:

- your component should have an `id` property that is passed to the form element you want to check (which is most likely the case anyway)

Answer (score 12):

Using hooks:

First you create and initialize your Reference

```
const yourElement = useRef(null)
```

Then You tag your element with the reference you have just created:

```
<div ref={yourElement}>Im an DOM node</div>
```

And then, you use this logic as you need to compare if the `document.activeElement` document property is equal to the DOM node you are referencing to

```
yourElement.current === document.activeElement
```

Answer (score 10):

There is a much easier approach with hooks. Make an import:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
```

Define:

```
const [isMyInputFocused, setIsMyInputFocused] = useState(false);
```

And in your chosen input just add:

```
onBlur={() => setIsMyInputFocused(false)}
onFocus={() => setIsMyInputFocused(true)}
```

And from now on you could access the `isMyInputFocused` as you wish.

Comment: This is a "psudeo focus" and will not scale well:

eg: If there were 10 inputs you would have to hoist this state and start managing refs or this state would need to be applied to each input and there is a risk of it going out of sync

Comment: Amazing answer thank you. I'm using this for a sibling relationship on single use so this works just fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Using functional component you can determine if the current input has focus:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = React.createRef(null);

  const handleMouseOut = (currentRef) => {

    if (document.activeElement === currentRef) {
      console.log("Yesss");
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={ref}
        onMouseOut={() => handleMouseOut(ref.current)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you can use `onFocus` (React 17) or `onBlur` (React 16) to implement the functionality that you want when these things are in focus.

Answer (score 0):

***Adjusting answer from @Abhishek E H, there will be a little delay if you use onMouseOut but using onFocus works perfectly fine.
Thank you for the inspiration.

---

```
import React from "react";

 export default function App() {
   const ref = React.createRef(null);

   const handleMouseOut = (currentRef) => {

if (document.activeElement === currentRef) {
  console.log("Yess");
   }
 };
return (
<div className="App">
  <input
    type="text"
    ref={ref}
    onFocus={() => handleMouseOut(ref.current)}
  />
</div>
```

);
}

Comment: This is the exact same answer as the one you name, except with bad formatting, isn't it?

Comment: Almost exactly but I changed the onMouseOut to onFocus since onFocus updates the handleMouseOut immediately the input is on focus but there is a delay with onMouseOut