# How leave from infinite rerender?

Tags: reactjs

When blur, I want the **blurEvent** function to be executed, it is executed but then goes into an infinite loop because of **inputRef.current.blur ();**. But I need to somehow get out of the input focus. How can this problem be solved?

```
const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
const blurEvent= () => {
  inputRef.current.focus({
    cursor: 'start',
  })
     inputRef.current.blur();
}
<Input
  placeholder="Name"
  required
  ref={inputRef}
  onBlur={blurEvent}
/>
```

with useState()

```
const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false)
const inputRef = React.useRef(null)
const handleOnBlur = () => {
  if (isFocused) {
    inputRef.current.focus({
      cursor: 'start',
    })
    inputRef.current.blur()
  }
  setIsFocused(false)
}
<Input
  placeholder="Name"
  required
  ref={inputRef}
  onFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
  onBlur={blurEvent}
/>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? If you have a function calling itself its going to be infinite. You could define a state that is toggled by onBlur() and onFocus() and then use that state to decide what to do with the ref. Something like:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619285/detect-whether-input-element-is-focused-within-reactjs

Comment: Also if you are using a newer version of 16 or above of react you should be using `createRef()` not `useRef()` https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @stiyale I tried use useState to handle state onBlur and onFocus. Added with useState example. But it still doesn't work

Comment: explain what you are trying to accomplish, and we will be able to better help you. There may be a better way to do what you are trying to do. For future reference it helps to explain WHAT you want your code to do in your og post.

Comment: @StiyAle Im trying to put cursor at start in input before blur event

Comment: The blurEvent occurs when a input box is left, are you sure you don't mean to put the cursor at the beginning on the focus event? Why do you need the cursor to return to the beginning after leaving the input?

Answer (score 1):

You can give that task to two event functions with a boolean as follows.

```
const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
const [isAutoFocused,setIsAutoFocused] = useState(false)
const blurEvent= () => {
  inputRef.current.focus({
    cursor: 'start',
  })
  setIsAutoFocused(true)
}
const focusEvent = () => {
    if (!isAutoFocused){
        return
    }
    inputRef.current.blur();
    setIsAutoFocused(false)
}
<Input
  placeholder="Name"
  required
  ref={inputRef}
  onBlur={blurEvent}
  onFocus={focusEvent}
/>
```

Comment: this code doesn't work, cuz after click out of input infinite loop start again

Comment: Then try it by wrapping useCallBack hook