# How to know if an input is clicked and unclicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

I'm trying to figure out how to know when an input is clicked and when it is unclicked. Let me explain:

When ever you want to type something on an input field, you click on the input box and when you don't want to type, you click somewhere else and the input field is disabled.

```html
<input type='text'>
```

Here as you can see, when you click on it, the field is enabled, and when you click somewhere else other than the field, it disables.

I just want to know when the field is disabled/unclicked.

Comment: It is not disabled. That is something totally different. You want Focus and Blur events.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect whether input element is focused within ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619285/detect-whether-input-element-is-focused-within-reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the input field focus event is fired. When you lose focus blur event is fired.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("fname")

elem.addEventListener("blur", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  alert("Input field lost focus.");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname">
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're just looking for `onFocus`.

```
<input type='text' onFocus={/* do something */} />
```

Read more about React events [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).